# How block all applications in low memory scenario

Tags: android, low-memory

I wrote code such that if phone internal memory becomes less than 10% of total internal memory then it'll show low memory dialog and it'll take user to managapplications activity to free some memory. but if user is not freeing also it's allowing user to fill the remaining internal memory. How can i block all the other applications till it satisfies the memory condition(>10% of total low memory).

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You may want to tell us which kind of phone OS you're talking about. Android (I would guess so, given your favorite tags)? iOS? Windows Mobile?

Comment: I'm developing this on android OS.Thanks for replying Mr.Joubarc

Comment: You're welcome, I added the Android tag for you. That said, I don't know how to do what you want, but I'm not sure it's even a good idea - Android manages that kind of stuff automatically by itself.

Comment: Yeah Android manages but it's giving only notification, so few users ignore that and they keep filling the internal memory, then because of low memory all applications getting killed. to avoid such scenario we should notify user...

Answer (score 0):

> How can i block all the other applications till it satisfies the memory condition(>10% of total low memory).

Fortunately, you cannot, except perhaps by putting your feature in custom firmware.